# Why am i losing tranny fluid but no leak

Tags: transmission, fluid

I have to put more in about ever month and have no leaks any where and also will pulling a small trailer hurt my 2008 entoroge van

Answer (score 4):

If you are having to add fluid regularly then you do have a leak - transmission fluid doesn't just evaporate, it has to go somewhere for the level to go down. The leak may be small and hard to detect, but it will be there. You probably think there's no leak because you don't find a pool of fluid underneath your car, however it may only be leaking when the vehicle's being driven as that's when fluid is being circulated and under pressure.

The most likely cause is a fluid seal having deteriorated, hard to say which one as it varies by model and options. If it's a slightly leaky seal you're probably all right for pulling a trailer, however you need to keep in mind that a small leaks have a tendency to become big leaks, especially when a transmission is under strain.

Another possibility is that you have a crack in your torque converter which is allowing fluid to leak out. If this is the case then I wouldn't pull a trailer as the additional strain could make it worse of give up all together in which case your transmission will fail spectacularly, and murphy's law states it will be at the worst possible moment.

Often ignoring small problems leads to bigger and more expensive repairs down the road. I would get it fixed, that way you can rely on it.

Comment: Is it possible to leak from transmission to engine side(clutch, flywheel etc)?

Comment: No, you can't leak transmission fluid into your engine. They are mechanically connected but there's no way for fluid to get from one to the other.